Microsoft Exchange - ADFS- OWA - KEYCLOAK
I have encountered a problem with an ADFS in Exchange Server 2019.
x-adfserror: ID4175: The issuer of the security token was not recognized by the IssuerNameRegistry. To accept security tokens from this issuer, configure the IssuerNameRegistry to return a valid name for this issuer.
Im using keycloak as IDP to login to OWA.
The connection between is setup like this OWA - ADFS - KEYCLOAK(our mfa handling) - ADFS - OWA.
In relying party trust in ADFS for OWA i have put identifier: https://link/owa/. Should it be https://link/adfs/services/trust/? Tried but im getting 503 error while accessing this link.
I saw that there is a STS configuration, but cannot find what exacly it is doing for ADFS.
The connection between adfs and keycloak works well. Can login.
Tried link change to service/trust
